# How to get rid of request payload and pass parameters to the save fuction in backbonejs in javascript?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to use backbone.js model, collection and view alongwith my rest api. I wanted to ask how can I perform the PUT, DELETE and POST operations in backbone model and how to pass parameters to these requests dynamically?

The ajax setup passes the store the data globally but these are not applied to my PUT and POST requests. Also when I tracked the network traffic I can see that the request still carries the request payload. Can you please let me know how can I get rid of this?

Comment: Could you provide some sample code to demonstrate the problem more clearly?